# Triple Integral in cylindrical coordinate

Tags: integration

Let E be the region bounded above by the paraboloid $z=4- x^2 - y^2$ in the first octant and $f(x,y,z)=5\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ be the density of the solid E.

a) Set up an integral for the volume E.

b) Find the mass of the solid E.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) The volume is given by

$$V = \iiint_E dV = \int_0^2 dr \, r \, \int_0^{4-r^2} dz \, \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta$$

b) The mass of this object is given by the volume integral over the density, or

$$M = 5 \iiint_E \rho\,  dV = 5 \int_0^2 dr \, r^2 \, \int_0^{4-r^2} dz \, \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta$$

or

$$M = \frac{5 \pi}{2} \int_0^2 dr \, r^2 (4-r^2) $$

Can you take it from here?  I get $M = 32 \pi/3$.

Comment: wait howd you know the r goes from 2 to 0

Comment: Because in the plane $z=0$ where the cross-section is biggest, $x^2+y^2=r^2=4$.